# TeamCity build fails because of TypeScript - TS2304 and TS7006

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, teamcity, visual-studio-2017

TeamCity Enterprise 2017.1 (build 46533) build fails - Builds fine with `Visual Studio 2017 Pro`.

Build Steps in TeamCity:

```
NuGet Installer 
Node.js NPM 
Visual Studio (sln) -> Set for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017
```

Gets these errors even though it builds fine on my local machine. I have `"noImplicitAny": true` in `.tsconfig` and do not wan't to change it regarding `TS7006`. How come I get these errors in TeamCity but not on my local machine?

Complete error log: https://pastebin.com/Wj0f7pXr

I have an idea for the last two errors with `TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'object'.`. It says in log:

`[10:36:35] [VsTsc] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.1\tsc.exe --project "T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\tsconfig.json" --listEmittedFiles`

object was added in `TypeScript 2.2` but it still does not explain the other errors.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html

TypeScript information from build server:

```
C:\Users\COMPANY-BUILD-01>tsc --version
Version 2.3.4

C:\Users\COMPANY-BUILD-01>where tsc
C:\Users\COMPANY-BUILD-01\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
C:\Users\COMPANY-BUILD-01\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
```

Compilation error (1):

```
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(47, 9): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'fetch'.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(47, 40): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(49, 18): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'aboutModel' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(52, 9): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'fetch'.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(52, 40): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(54, 18): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'factsModel' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(57, 9): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'fetch'.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(57, 43): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(59, 18): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'sidePaneModel' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(62, 9): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'fetch'.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(62, 41): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(64, 18): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'footerModel' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(67, 9): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'fetch'.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(67, 42): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(69, 18): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'optionsModel' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(72, 9): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'fetch'.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(72, 44): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\App.tsx(74, 18): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'contactModel' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\Inventory\index.tsx(24, 9): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'fetch'.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\Inventory\index.tsx(24, 44): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\Features\Client\Inventory\index.tsx(26, 18): error TS7006: Build:Parameter 'inventory' implicitly has an 'any' type.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\node_modules\@types\react-router\index.d.ts(82, 23): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'object'.
T:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\603ae47e37445f5d\Project\Project.Web\node_modules\@types\react-router\index.d.ts(83, 13): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'object'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked VS Developer command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>tsc --version
Version 2.1.5
```

I then tried to download the latest version from TypeScripts home page for VS 17 but it still showed the same result.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links

I then started Visual Studio on the dev server -> Tools -> Extensions and updates... -> Product Updates -> Installed the latest Visual Studio Update. For me it was `Visual Studio Update 15.2 (26430.13)`.

This version bumped TypeScript to 2.2.3 and solved all errors.

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0.26430.13
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>tsc -v
Version 2.2.3
```